# Individual Kafka consumer group behavior when listening to multiple topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two Kafka topics(topic_1,topic_2) and both of them are configured in the same Kafka server. I have two consumer applications and **they are in the same consumer group**.

In my POC, I first start consumer application 1 (which listens to topic_1). After some time, I start consumer application 2 (which listens to topic_2).

When application 2 starts running, partitions will be revoked in application 1. I could not figure out the reason for this since they are separately listening to topics and only the common attribute among them is the consumer group id. When I use different group ids I did not observe this behaviour. Appreciate it if someone could explain the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: It is generally best practice to use a different consumer group for consumers on unrelated topics, for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can override the `Assignor` class (`partition.assignment.strategy`) to be more sticky and reduce rebalances, this is expected behavior.

Adding and removing any client to a group will invoke a rebalance, regardless of what topics are used.

Comment: It is generally best practice to use a different consumer group for consumers on unrelated topics, for exactly this reason.